# Error getting response.body and converting to String

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, retrofit2

I´am using retrofit 2.0 to get GSON from Youtube API address:

[Link (temporarily static) for Youtube Address](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLbZ3V_t0ZLzylEoYuPtmT5uArAzMewz-m&fields=items/snippet/resourceId/videoId&key=AIzaSyAH2YDhp_Yle3NhLeCuBqH654lUre4vDHw)

[GSON from Youtube address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL0Xx.png)

But when I try to get the videoID from response.body it doesn´t work!

My code:

```
public class Videos {


    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("videoId") String mVideoId;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("title") String mTitle;

   public Videos(String videoId, String title ) {
        this.mVideoId = videoId;
        this.mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getmVideoId() {
        return mVideoId;
    }
    public void setmVideoId(String mVideoId) {
        this.mVideoId = mVideoId;
    }
    public String getmTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
    public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

}
```

My interface:

```
public interface YoutubeApiURL {

@GET("youtube/v3/playlistItems")
Call<Videos> listVideos (
    @Query("part") String part,
    @Query("maxResults") String maxResults,
    @Query("playlistId") String playlistId,
    @Query("fields") String fields,
    @Query("key") String key
);
}
```

And here my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    btnListar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnListaGitHub);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    YoutubeApiURL service = retrofit.create(YoutubeApiURL.class);


    Call<Videos>  videos = service.listVideos(
            "snippet",
            "50",
            "PLbZ3V_t0ZLzylEoYuPtmT5uArAzMewz-m",
            "items/snippet/resourceId/videoId",
            "AIzaSyAH2YDhp_Yle3NhLeCuBqH654lUre4vDHw");

    myURL = videos.request().url().toString();
    Log.i("ListVideos", myURL);


    videos.enqueue(new Callback<Videos>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Videos> call, Response<Videos> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("ListVideos","Works!");
                // Here some code to show de videoIds return
            } else {
                Log.i("ListVideos","Something wrong");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Videos> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("ListVideos: ", t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

When I ran my code it shows to me that "Works!", but I tried in several ways to get the videoID with no success!
What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a model class wrong. try below

Videos

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Videos {

@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = null;

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public Videos withItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    return this;
}

}
```

Snippet

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Snippet {

@SerializedName("resourceId")
@Expose
private ResourceId resourceId;

public ResourceId getResourceId() {
    return resourceId;
}

public void setResourceId(ResourceId resourceId) {
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
}

public Snippet withResourceId(ResourceId resourceId) {
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    return this;
}

}
```

ResourceId

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResourceId {

@SerializedName("videoId")
@Expose
private String videoId;

public String getVideoId() {
    return videoId;
}

public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
    this.videoId = videoId;
}

public ResourceId withVideoId(String videoId) {
    this.videoId = videoId;
    return this;
}

}
```

Item

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Item {

@SerializedName("snippet")
@Expose
private Snippet snippet;

public Snippet getSnippet() {
    return snippet;
}

public void setSnippet(Snippet snippet) {
    this.snippet = snippet;
}

public Item withSnippet(Snippet snippet) {
    this.snippet = snippet;
    return this;
}

}
```

Now for get Video id use below code in success method

```
response.body().getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId();
```

Comment: @Andre Happy to help you, if answer helped you then don't forgot to accept it as right answer.